# SwiftData, save and retrieve data from the user

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm having a problem with SwiftData. I want to read data from the user and save it in SwiftData. I think that my code works well except for saving the data. I think the error is in the works method, because I gave it initial values ​​again. My main question is, how can I save data from the user and retrieve it at any time?

Also my when I run the code, it shows this:

[image]

When I add all the data and press done it shows this.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  addexc
//
//  Created by Foundation 46 on 06/05/1445 AH.
//

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct sheetview: View {
 
 @Environment (\.modelContext) private var Context
 @Environment (\.dismiss) private var dismiss
 @Query(sort: \data.day) var workout : [data]
 enum Day: String, CaseIterable {
  case Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat
 }
 @Binding var sheets : Bool
 @State private var selectedNumber: Int = 1
 @State private var selectedNumber2: Int = 1
 @State private var selectedDay: Day = .Mon
 @State private var workname : String = ""
 @State private var excname : String = ""
 
 var body: some View {
  NavigationView{
   VStack{
    HStack {
     Text("Workout Name").bold()
     Spacer()
     TextField("EX: legs", text: $workname ).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    }
    
    HStack{
     Text("Day").bold()
     Spacer()
     ForEach(Day.allCases, id: \.self) { day in
      Button(action: {
    selectedDay = day
      }) {
    Text(day.rawValue).foregroundColor(Color.black)
      }
      .background(
    Capsule()
     .fill(selectedDay == day ? .colorsy :Color(UIColor.white))     )
      .clipShape(Capsule())
      
     }
     
     
    }
    
    
    Divider()
    HStack {
     Text("Exercise Name").bold()
     TextField("EX: Narrow Stance Leg Press", text: $excname ).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    }
    ZStack{
     
     HStack {
      Spacer()
      Picker("Number of Sets", selection: $selectedNumber){
    ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { number in
        Text("\(number)")
     
    }
      }.frame(width: 102.0, height: 25.0)
     }
     HStack {
      
      Text("Number of sets:").bold()
      Spacer()
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13).stroke(.gray).frame(width: 133,height: 25)
     }
    }
    
    ZStack{
     
     HStack {
      Spacer()
      Picker("Number of reps", selection: $selectedNumber2){
    ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { number in
     Text("\(number)")
     
    }
      }.frame(width: 102.0, height: 25.0)
     }
     HStack {
      
      Text("Number of reps:").bold()
      Spacer()
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13).stroke(.gray).frame(width: 133,height: 25)
     }
    }
    
    Divider()
    Button(action: {
    works()
     try! Context.save()
     dismiss()
   
    }
    )   {
     ZStack{
      Capsule()
    .frame(width: 130, height: 25.0)
    .cornerRadius(50)
      //  .background(Color.colorsy)
    .padding()
      
      Text("done")
    .font(.body)
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
     }}
   }
  
   .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action:{ sheets.toggle()}
, label:{
    Text("cancel")
    
   }))
  }
   .padding()
 }
 func works () {
  let workout = data(Excname: "", workname: "", numofsets: 0, numofreps: 0, day: "")
  Context.insert(workout)
 }
 
  
}
  
// #Preview {
//  sheetview()
// }

---------------------another view page ---------------------------
//
//  wow.swift
//  addexc
//
//  Created by Foundation 46 on 09/05/1445 AH.
//

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct wow: View {
    @Environment (\.modelContext) private var context
    @Query(sort: \data.day) var workout: [data]
    @State private var sheets = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                sheets.toggle()
            } , label: {
                /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Text("Button")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
            })
            
        
            NavigationStack{
                List {
                    ForEach (workout) { workout in
                        Text(workout.workname)
                        Text(workout.Excname)
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            .sheet(isPresented: $sheets){
                sheetview(sheets: $sheets)
            }
            .padding()}
       
    }}


#Preview {
    wow()
}
```

Comment: Do yourself, and us, a favor and start being more consistent when naming types and properties. Follow the praxis for Swift and start type names with an uppercase letter and properties and variables with a lowercase letter. As for your code, in the function `works` you should use the properties the user has edited when creating your `data` object. `let workout = data(Excname: excname, workname: workname, …)`

Answer (score 2):

In `works()` you are giving the `Context` a `data` object with `Excname = ""` and `workname = ""`. And then when it comes to displaying that data you do:

```swift
List {
  ForEach (workout) { workout in
    Text(workout.workname)
    Text(workout.Excname)
  }
}
```

Which because `Excname = ""` and `workname = ""` is the same as:

```swift
List {
  ForEach (workout) { workout in
    Text("")
    Text("")
  }
}
```

Resulting in the empty rows you see. If you want to create a relationship between what a user enters and what gets saved you'd pass the variables in your View.

```swift
func works() {
  let workout = data(Excname: excname, workname: workname, numofsets: numofsets, numofreps: numofreps, day: day)
  Context.insert(workout)
}
```

Also, you do not need to do `Context.save()`, as mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10154/?time=655:

> You might think that after inserting the model, you need to save the context, calling "modelContext.save()," but you don't need to do that. A nice detail about SwiftData is that it autosaves the model context.

Comment: can you explain more , I kinda get the error but how can I send these variables when they are from the user

Comment: okaaayyy I get it now thanks a lot